# JavaScript functions return value is undefined snapshot from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've got the following code. The return value of the function caloriex is always undefined.

When I show the value being returned just before the return statement it shows the correct value. But when it is returned from the function it is undefined. Can you please help me to resolve this?

```
  function caloriex(calorie, meal){
    let citiesRef = db.collection('food');
    let query = citiesRef.where('category_out', '==', calorie).where('category_in', '==', meal).get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log('No matching documents.');
        }
        var workingbalance = '';
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());//this result is fine
          workingbalance = doc.data().id;
        });
        return workingbalance //returned VALUE is undefined 
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you never return anything from the function.  All it's doing is `let` two variables, and then there are a bunch of callbacks from inner functions that don't affect the return of the outer function.  The statement `return workingbalance` is just returning that value from the inner lambda function that you passed then `then`.

You will have to learn how promises and promise chains works in JavaScript if you want to be effective with asynchronous programming.  If you want to get that `workingbalance` value to the caller, the best you can do is return the entire promise chain, and make the caller use `then` on that promise to get the value.  So, it will be

```
return citiesRef.where(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: Hi, i tried. but, i getting result  [object promise].

Comment: It should be `return citiesRef.where(...).get().then(...).catch(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning [object promise] because the promise is not resolved and you are returning the value. Please use "await" to call the Firestore function.